# Datetime column caused an overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error on running this below query. How should I handle it?

```
update a
set pidate = case 
when PromisedYear is not null 
then dateadd(week, cast(PromisedWeek as int), dateadd(year, PromisedYear - 1900, 0))
else '2020-12-31' 
end
FROM #CuringATPDualOutput1 a
```

Error:

> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

When Promisedweek is less than 59, like 44 or 45, the query is working fine. 
Only giving an error when it is 59.

Data:

```
44  2017
44  2017
44  2017
44  2017
44  2017
45  2017
45  2017
45  2017
45  2017
45  2017
46  2017
45  2017
45  2017
45  2017
45  2017
59  NULL
46  2017
59  NULL
45  2017
45  2017
46  2017
46  2017
46  2017
47  2017
47  2017
47  2017
48  2017
48  2017
48  2017
49  2017
49  2017
49  2017
50  2017
50  2017
50  2017
51  2017
51  2017
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please check the post, i have edited it.

Comment: How are you handling that NULL? If you're not, it is going to cause you issues.

Comment: So you are trying to add  59 + (2017 - 1900) in weeks.  Is 59 + 117 in weeks meaningful?   I'm lost as to why you are doing this and what it could possibly mean.

Comment: seconded leonidas null observation. you can't take 1900 from null

Comment: MardD and @Leonidas199x I have handling Null value. I have updated the post, with exact query I am using in my code.

Comment: Your code now works, the code you posted originally did not.

Comment: @Twelfth this query returns date based on week and year, and that date has the same day as that on the first day on the year. Means, if 2017 1st day is Tuesday, it will return tuesday's date of the provided week

Comment: @SeanLange sorry, I didnt get you. its still showing error

Comment: With the sample data you posted this code will NOT produce that error.

Comment: Even all the newly added data will not produce an error with the query you posted.

Comment: I managed to create the error with a year of 1752, using the year 1753 is fine. Anybody know of any reason 1752 would cause overflow but not 1753?

Comment: I dont know why its happening. But surely the 59 is causing error. cause I just added "where PromisedWeek != 59" in the update query, and it did run without errors @SeanLange

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with 59. I suspect there is something else in your data is causing an issue. Maybe a character in PromisedYear where PromisedWeek = 59?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your sample data and the query you posted. I even added some more rows of sample data that are greater than 59 and they work just fine. I suspect you have something else going on.

```
declare @Output table
(
    PromisedWeek int
    , PromisedYear int
    , pidate datetime
)

insert @Output values
(44, 2017, null)
, (45, 2017, null)
, (46, 2017, null)
, (47, 2017, null)
, (48, 2017, null)
, (49, 2017, null)
, (50, 2017, null)
, (51, 2017, null)
, (59, NULL, null)
, (59, 2017, null)
, (379, 2017, null)

update @Output
set pidate = case 
when PromisedYear is not null 
then dateadd(week, cast(PromisedWeek as int), dateadd(year, PromisedYear - 1900, 0))
else '2020-12-31' 
end

select * from @Output
```

In fact even your original code works with this data and will not throw an exception.

```
select dateadd(week, cast(PromisedWeek as int), dateadd(year, PromisedYear - 1900, 0))
from @Output
where PromisedWeek = 59
```

Comment: Hello Sean, can you please one last time try to run the update query? I have edited my post with the exact query of my code.

Comment: You should be able to test this pretty easily. i provided you a test harness. And your updated code still throws no error.

Comment: I think I got the error, my #CuringATOPDualOutput1 column PromisedYear have BLANK value, not NULL. I guess that is causing the error. is it possible? Null and Blank are different right?

Comment: Extremely different. You should get in the habit of storing datetime values in the appropriate datatype instead of varchar columns. An empty string when converted to a datetime will be 1/1/1900. NULL when converted to a datetime will be NULL. And if talking about integers, an empty string is 0.

Comment: Thank you for you advice. Surely Ill keep that in mind hence forth. Thank you for your guidance